Using python socket on android (and, any remote) app
I use socket in my kivy app, and until recently it was connected to a local server. 
Now I converted the python code to an apk, and connected the socket to the appropriate ip address however the app wont launch. Apparently due to a problem with the socket the problem I get now when running it is;
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

And shows that the problem is in the line of the connection to the socket
I didn't try to open the app from another comouter so I dont know if the problem happens for all clients that aren't on the local computer or only on the apk conberted app specifically.
The app opens and starts the kivy loading screen, after that the screen turns black for a good few seconds, than crushes with the error I've added above. This is very similar to what happens when I try to run the client without running the server first, the only difference is that the errorno is different (the details are still "Connection timed out", but the way the app behaves before crushing is the same), but to run the app, I DID run the server first and I've reasured I am connecting to the correct ip address
I've tried to disable the firewall on the server's side and it didn't help
(the error before disabling the firewall was "OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host")
Does anyone know how can I solve this?
p.s I've used kivy and python programming for the app, then converting it to an apk with buildozer. 
For all I know the app should work fine aside from the problems with the socket connection.
